# Images don't blit at a position of a multiple of 32

Tags: python, pygame, 2d

I am making a 2D minecraft clone using Pygame. Whenever I click the mouse button, a block places. The problem is that the blocks do not place at the correct position (snapping to a multiple of 32). I have a placeholder block that follows the mouse cursor and snaps to a grid, but when I place blocks they do not. Any idea on how to fix this?
Help would be appreciated. I have put the code and an image below.

[image: screenshot]

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((480,320))
pygame.display.set_caption(("2D Craft"))
block = pygame.image.load("Grass.png")
running = True

positions = []

def rtm(n, m):
    return round(n / m) * m

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            positions.append(event.pos)

    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    #snap to grid (multiple should be width and height of cube)
    mxr = rtm(mx, 32)
    myr = rtm(my, 32)

    #boundries
    if mxr > 448:
        mxr = 448
    if myr > 288:
        myr = 288

    win.fill("aqua")
    for pos in positions:
        win.blit(block, pos)
    win.blit(block, (mxr, myr))
    pygame.display.update()

#need to round event.pos to multiple of 32
```

Answer (score 0):

You must snap to the position which you store in the `positions` list, because these positions are later used to draw the blocks to their individual positions in the world.

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            px, py = event.pos  
            pxr = rtm(px, 32)
            pyr = rtm(py, 32)
            positions.append((pxr, pyr))

    # [...]
```

[image]